# Detect when ComboBox is clicked on Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mouseevent

I'm am trying to perform an action when my `combobox` has been clicked (not changed index).
Basically I want to grab some items from a directory every time user clicks on the combobox, but for some reason it doesn't seem to identify a click.. I got two functions but none of them fire away when I click:

```
private void cmblist_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  //do something
}

void cmblist_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   //do something
}
```

I assume that the body of the functions are not so important as they won't even fire..
How can I perform an action when the combobox is clicked?

Comment: Did you add the event handler to the combo box'es events? Maybe the [DropDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdown) event is more appropriate for your case as it also direct when opened via the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, you didn't add this method to your ComboBox.MouseClick event.

If you do this dynamically *(like all OOP programmers)* you can assign method this way:

```
        private void InitializeComboBox()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(cmbList);
            cmbList.MouseClick += CmbList_MouseClick;
        }

        private void CmbList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //do something...
        }
```

Other way, if you do this via WindowsForm Designer *(where you add everything manually)*, you should click **once** on your ComboBox and go to **Properties -> Events -> MouseClick** and from drop-down menu choose your method that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Try **OnMouseEnter** or **OnKeyPress** method.
I hope this this is what you're searching for.
You can find more details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=net-5.0

Comment: Hi! I think I should give a more detailed answer. Maybe need to showing finite winforms class.